# Logarithmic Question? What is a log with a base of 9 and a exponent of 9^11

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Logarithmic Question?

What is a $\log$ with a base of $9$ and an exponent of $9^{11}$? How do I evaluate?

$\log_9 9^{11} =\;?$

Comment: Use $\log(x^n) = n\log(x)$ and $\log_x(x) = 1$. Try and ask yourself why these formulas are true. Note that these formulas only hold for certain values of $x$.

Comment: Remember, $\log_a b$ answers the question "What exponent do I need to put on $a$ in order to arrive at $b$?" So in this case if you ask "What exponent do I need to put on $9$ in order to arrive at $9^{11}$?", then you can see the answer is $11$, right?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't ask this question if you knew the definition of the logarithm.

When you say $\log_a x=y$ it means that $a^y=x$.

In your case you want a number $y$ such that $9^y=9^{11}$. What could it be?

Comment: No need for the harsh language... this person is probably new to mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

$\log_9 9^{11}=11\log_99=11\cdot1=11$

Comment: Thanks you so much.